# Querying a collection via a match in an ID-to-ID collection in MongoDB using C# Driver

Tags: c#, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following collection document types:

```
Car
{
   Id
   Make
   Model
}
```

and

```
UserCar
{
   UserId
   CarId   (references Car.Id)
}
```

I'm having trouble finding the correct query using MongoDB C# Driver to:

> Get all Cars where UserId = x

This is a very simple query in SQL, so I'm quite frustrated that this is proving so difficult with their SDK (for me, at least). It's the ID-to-ID collection containing the filter that seems to be the issue. So, starting with:

```
var db = MongoUtil.GetDb();
var cars = db.GetCollection<Car>("Cars");
var userCars = db.GetCollection<UserCar>("UserCars");

List<Car> carsJoined = ??? where UserId = 1234
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with MongoDB .NET Driver `.Aggregate()` (Although the query below looks a bit complex).

```
var result = cars
    .Aggregate()
    .Lookup<UserCar, BsonDocument>(
        "UserCars", 
        "Id", 
        "CarId",
        "userCars")
    .Match(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter
        .ElemMatch<BsonValue>("userCars", new BsonDocument("UserId", 1234)))
    .Project<masterDocument>(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection
        .Exclude("userCars"))
    .ToList();
```

This is equivalent to the aggregate query

```
db.cars.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: { 
        from: "UserCars",
        localField: "Id"
        foreignField: "CarId",
        as: "userCars"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "userCars": {
        $elemMatch: {
          "UserId": 1234
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      userCars: 0,
      // Other fields: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: The first example didn't work. Apparently not all of LINQ is supported by the .NET Driver. I got an error message of `System.NotSupportedException: '$project or $group does not support {document}.'` This is unfortunate as the LINQ method is by far the most readable and simple. The second method worked perfectly!

Comment: Follow up... Assuming my `UserCars` class has a `IsFavorite` property, how would I include that in my results? A collection of:
`{
    Car
    IsFavorite
}
`

Comment: Hmmm, you need modify your `Car` class by adding property `[BsonElement("userCars")] public List<UserCar> UserCars { get; set; }`. And modify the query as: `cars.Aggregate().Lookup<UserCar, Car>(...).Match(Builders<Car>.Filters....).ToList();`